# Powershell - ConvertFrom-Json results in invalid property names

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell to hit a web service and using ConvertFrom-Json to convert the response to an object. However the object is created with property names that cannot be accessed from Powershell code.

[image]

How can I access the property value for the properties? Should I even bother with ConvertFrom-Json? Is there an easier alternative?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: I'm having trouble determining from your screenshot what the property names are. Can you include them in text? Also you can try to quote your property names like this: `$object."A weird property name"`

Comment: Sorry the first column are the property names the second the values and the third the data type. Mike Shepard's answer works for referencing theses properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nonstandard property names can be referenced by using quotes.

Example:

```
$variable.'some strange/nonstandard property name'
```